# jquery.on() get reference to attached listener

Tags: jquery, addeventlistener

I attach an event listeners:

```
selector.on('DOMSubtreeModified', {email: email}, handler);

function handler(event) {
                    if (hasLoaded()) {
                        selector.off('DOMSubtreeModified', handler);
                        otherStuff(event.email);
                    }
                }
```

This can happen multiple times and when the first event triggers the off method, all listeners get removed. Is it possible to trigger off only on for the specific attachment. something like:

```
var listener = selector.on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
                    if (hasLoaded()) {
                        selector.off(listener);
                        otherStuff(email);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `.one()` instead of `.on()`. It binds a handler that only runs one time for each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the selector when you call `.off()` use the target of the current event.

```
function handler(event) {
    if (hasLoaded()) {
        $(this).off('DOMSubtreeModified', handler);
        otherStuff(event.email);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove only one handler.

The doc says: 
A handler can also be removed by 
specifying the function name in the handler argument. When jQuery attaches an event handler, it assigns a unique id to the handler function.

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: He wants to remove the handler from a specific element, instead of all the elements that match the selector.

Answer (score -1):

You could use removeEventListener method.

```
var listener = selector.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    if (hasLoaded()){ 
        selector.removeEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', listener);
        otherStuff(email);
    } 
});
```

Comment: That's not how you use `removeEventListener()`. `addEventListener()` doesn't return anything, and the arguments to `removeEventListener` are the same as `addEventListener`.

Comment: Despite the @Barmar s comment... It works, but it needs to be: removeEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', listener);